# What is a polite form of proposing a fee for a service?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example I did agree to provide a service to my client and I'd like to tell them, how much I would charge for my services.

I can say: "It'll cost $100". But is it the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form sounds more polite:

> We charge $100 for this service.

Comment: "It'll cost" is active voice as well. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

Well this is similar to salary dance or -**how much you want, how much they are ready to give you**. There are two ways to settle this down.

*This service is charged $100*. (passive voice, it means this is fact said in a cold voice computer alike, no place for negotiation)

*This time this service will be just $100, but only because you are our special clients.* (indicates personal involvement, shows that the client is special)

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on if they explicitly asked or not.  Which is to say, there is not an "easy" way to say "Yo, you owe me 100 dollars!" So it's better to create a situation where they ask "How much is this going to cost?" so that you can then say "That service costs $100".  Once it's out of the way, send them a bill if you need to remind them later.

One easy way to get someone to ask for the price is to offer them two options, clearly of different values. They'll want to know the price so they can decide if they can afford the option that has more bells and whistles.

Comment: Oh, also, if you want to be totally exempt from giving prices, do what almost every doctor does and claim "I don't handle billing. My assistant can go over that with you."